# need an algorithm for continuity check: select a list of integer number to have best "coverage"

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, linear-algebra

this is an hardcore algorithm problem that i'm facing right now:

let's say there is a sorted list of integers L1:
1. the total length of the list is known which is N (e.g. N could be 1e7)
2. all the elements are between two known boundaries, A and B ,  ( A <<< B )
e.g. L1 = [ 2,5,10,15,18,19,21...]

Right now, I need to select a subset of the elements from the list L1 to form a new list L2 with the total length of M (M < N)
(e.g. M could equal N /10 )

to satisfy a condition: the new list L2 needs to have best "coverage";
by "coverage", it means that all the elements integers in the L2 need to be distributed in the L1's range, [A,B], as equally as possible. 
(a.k.a an unbiased sub-sampling method )

any help is deeply appreciated.

thanks for everyone's help and idea. I try to simplify the problem so that everyone (without the background knowledge can understand the problem). To define a rule for goodness of the coverage:

the ultimate goal is to achieve:

1. in the list L2, for any two neighbor element J and K, there are | J - K | , and the sum of this difference needs to be minimized
2. apply a given window with the total length of Q ( Q < M ) to list L2, and the number of elements within the window needs to be either equal (ideal situation) or almost equal

***Final Update: after some more research, it turns out that this is a famous problem of Ip programming, which has been solved by people in 70s. For more details, please read paper: *** 
http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~forest/G294download/MAX_COVER_RLC_CSR.pdf

thanks

Comment: all the integers in the list L1 will be unique

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation in a specific language? R, Python, C, ...?

Comment: How densely packed is `L1` ?  What is `N` as a fraction of `B-A` ?  What is the measure you use for goodness of coverage ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "distributed in the L1's range, [A,B], as equally as possible"? Is this a probabilistic choice, do you want the numbers "spread out" evenly as possible, or something else?

Comment: I *think* I see the hard part: given a skewed list, you need to "unskew" `L2` as much as possible.  For instance, with `L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 100]`, you have have a range of 1:100.  Given `M=3` (half of `N`), the "ideal" L2 would be either `[1, 50, 100]` or `[25, 50, 75]`.  You don't have those elements.  The correct solution would be `[1, 20, 100]`.

Comment: What is your metric for evaluating the spread of a set?  In the case I just gave, how does [1, 50, 100]` compare to `[25, 50, 75]` as a solution?  Why?

Comment: @MauritsEvers : this is a small part of a conceptual prototype design, and any major programming language will do. at this stage, i don't really care about the  programming language choice and performance

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : the overall density of the list L1 is not very densely populated, but in the L1, there are several regions that contains much more data points than the rest, which is due to the data merging.

Comment: @RoryDaulton : thanks for the feedback, and i have updated my question to clarify the criteria. basically, it is a probabilistic choice and the numbers needs to spread out evenly as possible

Comment: @Prune : you are right! you really get my question! due to the merging from several data source, the list L1 is skewed. For certain regions of the L1, the density of the data points are much higher than the rest...  also, to make my question more clear, i have specified the selection criteria for "good coverage". any idea for solving this kind of problems?

Comment: So generate a list of integers, at equal intervals, in `[A,B]`. That's a first approximation to `L2`.  Next, run through `L2` and replace any element not in `L1` by the nearest element of `L1`.

Comment: Your "good" metric measure very little.  Adjacent elements are `L2[n]` and `L2[n+1]`, with the first one always less (so the absolute value does nothing).  The sum of these differences is simply `L2[last] - L2[1]`, with no description at all of the internal distribution.  Square the terms, perhaps?

Comment: Your second point in the "ultimate goal" is not measurable; "equal or almost equal" is not possible in all cases, such as the example I gave.  You give us no measure of how to evaluate equality.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: your simple approximation doesn't work; try it on a skewed distribution, such as the simple case I gave.  You wind up using one element of `L1` multiple times.  If you're going to replace with the nearest unused element of `L1`, the final solution can vary, depending on where you begin.  However, I *would* have expected OP to come up with something like this as a first approximation.

Comment: @Prune: yes indeed, I too can see all sorts of deficiencies in my 'solution'.  But I don't think OP has got a really clear idea of the result she wants and a rough first guess is usually a good place to start.

Comment: @user3224611: you still haven't clarified the range requirement.  For the interval `[A,B]`, must `L2` contain `A` and `B`?  If not, *are* there any requirements with respect to that full range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is to utilize bucket sort of which bucket size is (A - B) / M. After mapping each element in l1 to its corresponding bucket, pick element randomly from each bucket to from the new list. If the new list is shorter than m, then I repeat the process. The following is my implementation in Python:

```py
import bisect
import random
import collections

def form_new_list(l1, m, a, b, res):
    if m <= 0:
        return

    bucket_size = int((b - a) / m)
    bucket_list = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, num in enumerate(l1):
        bucket_num = int(num / bucket_size)
        bucket_list[bucket_num].append(num)

    for _, nums in bucket_list.items():
        selected = random.choice(nums)
        position = bisect.bisect(res, selected)
        bisect.insort(res, selected)
        l1.remove(selected)

    form_new_list(l1, m - len(res), a, b, res)

    return res
```